# React app - npm run build - BrowserlistError

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Here is my problem. I try to create a blog. I have server side created with npx create-react-app (there is a server.js file) and a client side created with npx create-react-app.

This a code from server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = express();
const httpServer = http.Server(app);

app.use('/', express.static(path.resolve(path.dirname(''), './client/build')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(path.dirname(''), './client/build/index.html'));
});

httpServer.listen(PORT, () => console.warn(`Listening on port: ${PORT}`));
```

When I run build I receive an error:

[image]

[image]

Here is package.json file from server side:

```
{
  "name": "proba",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "npm --prefix client install && npm --prefix client run build",
    "dev": "nodemon server.js",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is package.json file from client side:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3000"
}
```

Do I have to change my scripts in package.json? What did I do wrong?

Comment: the "npm run build" generates the error?

Comment: I run build on the server side {build": "npm --prefix client install && npm --prefix client run build"}. I think install client works well, but problem generates client run build. However I'm not sure. I've just added another bigger screenshot.

Comment: You must be having a `.browserlistrc` file too in your codebase. You can either have a `.browserlistrc` or define `browserlist` in `package.json`, not both.